# Why can't Python's import work like C's #include?

Tags: python, c, import

I've literally been trying to understand Python imports for about a year now, and I've all but given up programming in Python because it just seems too obfuscated. I come from a C background, and I assumed that `import` worked like `#include`, yet if I try to import something, I invariably get errors.

If I have two files like this:

foo.py:

```
a = 1
```

bar.py:

```
import foo
print foo.a
input()
```

WHY do I need to reference the module name? Why not just be able to write `import foo`, `print a`? What is the point of this confusion? Why not just run the code and have stuff defined for you as if you wrote it in one big file? Why can't it work like C's #include directive where it basically copies and pastes your code? I don't have import problems in C.

Comment: Because namespaces are a honking good idea.

Comment: Here's @roippi's comment unpacked: ["Namespaces are one honking great idea — let's do more of those!"… Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159683/namespaces-are-one-honking-great-idea-lets-do-more-of-those-why) and more generically the [Wikipedia Namespace article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).

Comment: I suppose this is really two questions - could it, and should it? The answer to the first is yes, the answer to the second I think has been addressed...

Answer (score 9):

To do what you want, you can use (not recommended, read further for explanation):

```
from foo import *
```

This will import everything to your current namespace, and you will be able to call `print a`.

However, the issue with this approach is the following. Consider the case when you have two modules, `moduleA` and `moduleB`, each having a function named `GetSomeValue()`.
When you do:

```
from moduleA import *
from moduleB import *
```

you have a namespace resolution issue*, because what function are you actually calling with `GetSomeValue()`, the `moduleA.GetSomeValue()` or the `moduleB.GetSomeValue()`?

In addition to this, you can use the `Import As` feature:

```
from moduleA import GetSomeValue as AGetSomeValue
from moduleB import GetSomeValue as BGetSomeValue
```

Or

```
import moduleA.GetSomeValue as AGetSomeValue
import moduleB.GetSomeValue as BGetSomeValue
```

This approach resolves the conflict manually.

I am sure you can appreciate from these examples the need for explicit referencing.

* Python has its namespace resolution mechanisms, this is just a simplification for the purpose of the explanation.

Comment: Isn't this bad practice?

Comment: Right. `from foo import *` is bad practice for the reasons Lawrence outlines. This is why you have to reference the module name.

Comment: @turbulencetoo: or you can just import names explicitly. `from foo import a`.

Comment: Could you add a disclaimer to the first code example e.g., `#XXX DO NOT DO THIS, read further for the explanation`

Comment: there is no resolution issue GetSomeValue from moduleB wins.

Comment: Why introduce all this confusion just to solve a few name collisions? If you're having name collisions, that's your fault. Change your code. Why go through all this about making namespaces and binding names to modules just to prevent POSSIBLE screwups, instead of having the programmer write correct code in the first place? Just define code, and use it. This is a very simple thing. Idk why Python wouldn't do that.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: you are wrongly assuming that you are the sole author of all the code. But different programmers work on different modules, and many of third party modules can be used in your application. You can not make sure they all have unique function and variable names. This would be silly, really the namespaces are the best solution if you think about it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the "resolution" issue is from the programmer pov. Just a simplified description to emphasize the issue. I have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Lawrence There is a near-infinite amount of ways to name a function. There is never, ever an excuse for naming collisions. Ever.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: I don't think you understand the issue. Take a look at following case. One person is developing a TCP client library. It will obviously have the Connect() method, because that is what a TCP client does. Meanwhile, on the other part of the world, someone is developing an HTTP client. It is obvious he will implement the Connect function for it. A few days later, someone decides that he wants to create an application that needs the TCP and HTTP client functionalities, but doesn't want to develop it. He wants to use third party modules, and he includes the two previous ones...

Comment: We can not expect the first person to use the Connect135315235() name for his TCP client, and the other one to use Connect234265() name for the HTTP client, just so that the third person could use those modules while avoiding a simple import statement in his application. The namespaces are only as genius as they are natural. And they are.

Comment: @Lawrence You're issuing a strawman argument. In that case, you could just name the functions with a prefix related to your particular files, like how OpenGL prefixes all their function names with gl to tell them apart from other functions. In your case, you could use the function names TCPConnect() and HTTPConnect() as the raw function names. This is another case that can be resolved without having to resort to namespaces.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere:  It seems that your beef is with namespaces and not particularly with Python.  It also seems that you are in the minority seeing that namespaces are a common design decision in recent programing languages.  For a list of drawbacks of not having namespaces see [Emulating Namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace#Emulating_namespaces) in the Wikipedia article  on Namespace.  If your philosophical difference is so great you may wish to stop using Python and revert to C.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Most modern programming languages use namespaces and for a good reason. If you don't like the mentioned benefit of function name separation, there are other benefits to namespaces too, like the fact that you could change the complete sets of functions you call by changing only one line of code, i.e. changing the namespace used, which can be useful in a number of cases. There are other benefits that you could investigate if you spend more time understanding the reasons and less time fighting the different way of thinking.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: just to add another point about namespaces. I guess that you have some files on your computer with the same names but in the different directories. Why don't you put them all in the same directory but add a prefix to them? Because thats not the natural way of doing things. Directories are namespaces, and they allow multiple files with the same name to co-exist as long as they are in the different folder.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: does this answer your question?

Comment: I guess I didn't realize they were namespaces at the time. The Python docs explained it in the most confusing way possible. I'm already very familiar with the working of namespaces, so I understand that. So I think the simplest answer to my question would have been "Because you are making a namespace."

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have your a function in your module which chooses some object from a list:

```
def choice(somelist):
    ...
```

Now imagine further that, either in that function or elsewhere in your module, you are using `randint` from the `random` library:

```
a = randint(1, x)
```

Therefore we

```
import random
```

You suggestion, that this does what is now accessed by `from random import *`, means that we now have *two different functions called choice*, as `random` includes one too. Only one will be accessible, but you have introduced ambiguity as to what `choice()` actually refers to elsewhere in your code.

This is why it is bad practice to import everything; either import what you need:

```
from random import randint
...
a = randint(1, x)
```

or the whole module:

```
import random
...
a = random.randint(1, x)
```

This has two benefits:

1. You minimise the risks of overlapping names (now and in future additions to your imported modules); and
2. When someone else reads your code, they can easily see where external functions come from.

Comment: We have only one function called `choice` whatever comes later.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes, that is correct, I meant that there is ambiguity as to what `choice` refers to - I will make this clearer

Comment: Or you could just change the name of your function so that the name collision doesn't happen. Once again, very simple thing, obfuscated over to prevent screwups. An ounce of prevention is a pound of cure. If you think there's going to be a naming collision, change the function name to something else. If you're having problems with `choice()` change it to `choice_of()` or something like that. I don't think there should be so much in place here, just run the file and have the names defined for you.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: do you control, read and remember the source code for all versions of all modules that you import on all systems?

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere but that means the developer now has to check through every name in every module they've imported when creating a new function or adding a new import. It also, as I refer to at the end, means that some later reader of the code may have to go back through all the imported modules to figure out where a particular class or function came from.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian No, and that is not a requirement. If there is a name collision, Python will be able to tell me where it is so I can make the necessary changes.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere: You need 100% test code coverage for that and the tests should be thorough enough to trigger the difference in behaviour Functions with the same name may have similar functionalities. Python is a dynamic language. Anyway, your code shouldn't break because of the things that you do not use. If you use a single function from a module, you shouldn't care about other functions in that module that it has today and those that will be introduced in the future versions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few good reasons. The module provides a sort of namespace for the objects in it, which allows you to use simple names without fear of collisions -- coming from a C background you have surely seen libraries with long, ugly function names to avoid colliding with anybody else.

Also, modules themselves are also *objects*.  When a module is imported in more than one place in a python program, each actually gets the same reference.  That way, changing `foo.a` changes it for everybody, not just the local module.  This is in contrast to C where including a header is basically a copy+paste operation into the source file (obviously you can still share variables, but the mechanism is a bit different).

As mentioned, you can say `from foo import *` or better `from foo import a`, but understand that the underlying behavior is actually different, because you are taking `a` and binding it to your local module.

If you use something often, you can always use the `from` syntax to import it directly, or you can rename the module to something shorter, for example

```
import itertools as it
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `import foo`, a new `module` is created inside the current namespace named `foo`.

So, to use anything inside foo; you have to address it via the module.

However, if you use from `from foo import something`, you don't have use to prepend the module name, since it will load `something` from the module and assign to it the name `something`. (Not a recommended practice)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import importlib

# works like C's #include, you always call it with include(<path>, __name__)
def include(file, module_name):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    # spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    o = spec.loader.get_code(module_name)
    exec(o, globals())
```

For example:

```py
#### file a.py ####
a = 1

#### file b.py ####
b = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hi, this is b.py")

#### file main.py ####
# assuming you have `include` in scope 
include("a.py", __name__)
print(a)
include("b.py", __name__)
print(b)
```

the output will be:

```
1
Hi, this is b.py
2
```